# Reuse patch statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I have these two statements repeating in many of my unit tests.

```
        with patch('/path') as mocked_thing1:
            mocked_thing1.return_value = 'some value'
            with patch('/path') as mocked_thing2:
                mocked_thing2.return_value = 'some value'
```

Is there a way I can write a function for it and just call it instead of writing these lines repeatedly in my test cases?

Comment: you can make a function with those lines then import it in each test but I see that path will be always changing!?

Comment: pytest fixtures will help.

Comment: A fixture certainly is the way to go. How to do this depends: is the path and 'some value' always the same? Do you need to access the mocked objects in your test afterwards?

Comment: 'some value' will be changing but path will remain same. And I do not need to access the mocked objects afterwards.

Comment: These lines wont always be needed to be executed at the start of every test case. In fact in some of the cases I need to generate this 'some value' first and then mocked return value should be set to this 'some value'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the return value for different tests, you have no way but to assign the return value in each test. One way would be to add separate fixtures for the mocks:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def mock_thing1():
    with patch('/path') as mocked_thing1:
        yield mocked_thing1

@pytest.fixture
def mock_thing2():
    with patch('/path') as mocked_thing2:
        yield mocked_thing2

def test_something(mock_thing1, mock_thing2):
    mocked_thing1.return_value = 'some value'
    mocked_thing2.return_value = 'some value'
    ...
```

Another possibility is to use indirect fixture parameters to set the return value in the fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def mock_thing1(request):
    with patch('/path') as mocked_thing1:
        mocked_thing1.return_value = request.param
        yield mocked_thing1

@pytest.fixture
def mock_thing2(request):
    with patch('/path') as mocked_thing2:
        mocked_thing2.return_value = request.param
        yield mocked_thing2


@pytest.mark.parametrize("mock_thing2", ['some other value'], indirect=True)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("mock_thing1", ['some value'], indirect=True)
def test_something(mock_thing1, mock_thing2):
    ...
```

Or you could just use the decorator version of `patch` instead of any fixture, so that at least the test body is better readable:

```py
@mock.patch("mock_thing2", return_value='some other value')
@mock.patch("mock_thing1", return_value='some value')
def test_something(mock_thing1, mock_thing2):
    ...
```