# How do I reuse a complicated patch statement?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have code that looks like this:

```py
with patch("package.module.func") as f1, \
   patch("package.module.func2") as f2, \
   patch("package.module.func3") as f3, \
   patch("package.module.func4") as f4:
      # Do something with the patched functions
```

I would like to avoid repeating this context over and over again in my code. I always want the same behaviour in different places.

One approach would be to use decorators and decorate my test class:

```py
@patch("package.module.func")
class TestSomething:
   # do stuff
```

AFAIK every test of `TestSomething` now uses the patches.

But if I use the patches again in multiple classes, I have to rewrite the decorators. **Is there a way to write these patches only once and reuse them in different test modules?**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63668387/reuse-patch-statements) does not answer my question, since the question is about having different return values per function, which I don't require.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution after a good coffee:

Mock example taken from this [YT: How to use Python's unittest.mock.patch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFRljVPHrkE)

```py
class BaseMock(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.patcher = mock.patch('src.examplemodule.print_content_cwd', return_value=b"[\"base mocked\"]")
        self.patcher.start()

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.patcher.stop()

# Use the mocking, without defining it again 
class TestDerived1(BaseMock):
    def test_d(self):
        ls = examplemodule.print_content_cwd()
        print(f"TestDerived1: ls returned {ls}\n")

# Use the mocking, without defining it again
class TestDerived2(BaseMock):
    def test_d(self):
        ls = examplemodule.print_content_cwd()
        print(f"TestDerived2: ls returned {ls}\n")
```

The code we want to mock in `src/examplemodule.py`:

```py
from subprocess import check_output
def print_content_cwd():
    return check_output(['ls']).split()
```